# How to uniquely identify an OS on a computer?

Tags: windows, linux, operating-system

Currently, I must uniquely identify an OS on a computer.

Now I use the serial of a disk and a partition number, which means the OS is installed in that partition of the disk. Because I think only one OS can be installed on one partition on a disk. So, that determines a unique OS.

Or, is there some better way to represent it?

Comment: Why are you asking? A user can legitimately have two variants of some OS and still consider having only one... And a Linux user could boot one of many different kernels on the same partition.

Comment: I want to identify all users of an OS instance. Initially, I considered uniquely identifying an OS, then appending their uid or sid. But I have difficulty to identify an OS instance. So, is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Uniquely* is a very slippery concept. Let's say I make VirtualBox machine image, and run five identical instances on my server. They'll all have the same disk serial number and the same partition id. Are they supposed to be the same, or different? Maybe you could add network address to the mix, so that could be the discriminator. But what if they are not networked?

There are many other possible grey areas: I can have a dozen different kernels on the same partition on a Linux system, and boot whichever one I choose at startup time. Should those all be the same, or different?

Early versions of Windows installed on top of a DOS install, and you booted in DOS and then brought up Windows on top of it. Are those two different OS's or just one?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ernest. All cases you mentioned above should be considered different OS instances. What I want to do is to identify all users of an OS instance. Please see comments of the question.